# websocket works on for index page

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, websocket

I have my website for using jsp. I wanted to use webcsocket to impement chatting. I tried a simple example to test whether it works or not. My code for server end point is given below:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package endpoint;

/**
 *
 * @author yashs
 */


import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
@ServerEndpoint("/echo")
public class MyServerEndPoint {

    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String message) {
        System.out.println("echo:" + message);
        return "Echoing " + message;
    }

}
```

The client side code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login V1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function debug(s) {
                var d = document.getElementById("debug");
                d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + "<br/>" + s;
            }
            function sendMessage(msg) {
                if (!("WebSocket" in window)) {
                    debug("Your browser does not support WebSocket.");
                    return;
                }
                var uri = "ws://" + document.location.host 
                        + document.location.pathname + "echo";
                var ws = new WebSocket(uri);

                ws.onopen = function () {
                    debug("Connected.");
                    ws.send("Hello");
                };

                ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                    debug("Received: " + evt.data);
                };

                ws.onclose = function () {
                    debug("Connection closed.");
                };
            }
        </script>

</head>
<body>


    <a href="javascript:sendMessage()">Send Message</a>
        <div id="debug"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

the name of my project is handiazza
the client side page is the index.html page which is automatically created when you create a new web application in netbeans. 
So when ever I run my app using

```
localhost:8084/handiazza/
```

then it works fine. But if I copy the same client side code and paste into a new file then it does not work. I saw many examples on google but all the examples have same mechanism of using localhost and the app name

Comment: Your server endpoint seems to be missing some Websockets code. [This netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html) should prove helpful.

Comment: I tried the example but the same problem still persists. It only works only when I run it on the index page and not on other pages.

Comment: that is it works only for the index .html page  and does not work on any other page

Comment: Well do you have the same websocket connections in other pages???

Comment: how can one say that one there are same websocket connections in other pages? What I did is copy pasted the client side code to another page. Is that using the same webscoket conection?